# VBA - How to resize a VBA UserForm based on its contents

Tags: vba, userform

Here is my problem:

I have a simple VBA UserForm and a Label **(Label1)** inside it which I called it **u1_Status** to inform users to what is happening behind the processes of my code. Its label will have different text at different stages of my code.

I want my UserForm size change according to the label inside it. For example when I have long informative text in Label1 I want my UserForm size increases and if label1 text in later stages is short my UserForm fits its dimensions to this updates text.

Here is my simplified code so far:

```
sub Test1()

Dim htLabelHeight: htLabelHeight = u1_Status.Label1.Height
Dim wdLabelWidth: wdLabelWidth = u1_Status.Label1.Width

u1_Status.Height = htLabelHeight
u1_Status.Width = wdLabelWidth
u1_Status.Show

end sub
```

The problem is that the width is Ok but the height seems to be Zero.

How my userform should looks:

[image: How my userform should looks]

How it Looks with my code:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The height of the userform also includes the height of the title bar. So you have to use the (read only) `InsideHeight` property of the userform.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    With Me
        Dim titleBarHeight As Long
        titleBarHeight = .Height - .InsideHeight
        .Label1.Caption = Sheet1.Range("A10")
        .Height = .Label1.Height + titleBarHeight
        .Width = .Label1.Width
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. You found what I was missing.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following code:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()

' Update Label1 caption based on cell A1
Me.Label1.Caption = Range("A1").Value

' Resize the userform based on the label height
Dim labelHeight As Integer
Dim formHeight As Integer

labelHeight = Label1.Height
formHeight = Me.Height

' Adjust the form height based on the label height and padding
Me.Height = labelHeight + 50 ' Change 50 to adjust for padding as needed
End Sub
```

Comment: Give a brief explanation.

Comment: It's gonna adjust both userform and label height, based on the quantity of content inside cell A1. Just need to adjust the width (label and userform) to the a size you need, as a delimitation of how much lines the label will read and consider as the criteria to adjust the height